# My view won't bind with my model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following viewmodel:

```
 public class CityViewModel
    {
        public CityViewModel() {     
            CityDetails = Enumerable.Range(1,2).Select(x => new CityDetail()).ToList(); 
        } 

        public City City { get; set; }
        public IList<CityDetail> CityDetails { get; set; }

        public class CityDetail
        {
            public CityDetail() {
                Correct = true;
            }
            public bool   Correct { get; set; }
        }
```

In my view I have the following:

```
        @foreach (int index in Enumerable.Range(0, Model.CityDetails.Count()))
        {
        <input type="hidden" name="CityDetails[@index]_Correct)" value="false" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="CityValid" name="CityDetails[@index]_Correct" value='@Model.CityDetails[index].Correct' />
```

I can't get any binding from the view to the model for the field named "Correct" so I am wondering about the naming that I used. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: You need to include more information.  What does your `@model` statement look like, why are you naming both models teh same name?

Comment: What about controller.. May you missing something there

Comment: public ActionResult Create(string pk, string rk) { var model = new CityViewModel();

Comment: Just checking... You're passing the model to the view, right? `return View(model);`

Comment: `name="CityDetails[@index]_Correct"` should be `name="CityDetails[@index].Correct"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy and best way to map collection is using the indexer. Use the following code snippet

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CityDetails.Count; i++)
 {
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.CityDetails[i].Correct)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for your view to look like that.  Create an editor template, and then use Html.EditorFor(x => x.CityDetails).  That will handle enumerating the collection and properly writing out the elements so that they map back into the list.